# what class or method am I in after find

Tags: pycharm

After doing a search or find on a large python file and the string is found how do I determine what method or class I am in.  The only way I can figure it out is to scroll to the top of the class or method. 
Pycharm 4.5 pro on Linux

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> which will show method name (if the name is not visible) or class name (if the class name is not visible).

You could open *Structure* tool window (View > Tool Windows > Structure , <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>) and turn on *Autoscroll from Source* option (button at the top of this window).

You can also vote on [IDEA-37112 Allow Nav Bar use beyond Class level (ie. methods)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-37112) which would show current class and method in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

In current releases there are support for `breadcrumbs`.  You can enable an configure this under Editor -> General -> Breadcrumbs.

Also helpful is that you can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> multiple times with each press taking you up a node.